# How do I delete symbols I scraped from websites in a csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

Iam trying to analyse airline reviews which is a single column dataframe containing only the text of the reviews, unfortunately there exist a tick symbol ✅ and special character | in each row showing whether the trip is verified or not, and after that | appears to separate the comment and the verification statement, I want to remove the verification text and the symbols.

```
data['reviews'] = data['reviews'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+', '')
```

I tried replacing the special characters using replace function:  regex=True),

```
data.replace(['\d+', r'(?u)[^\w\s\?]+', '\s*$'], ['','',''],
```

Comment: (1) Show code and other textual information as **properly formatted** text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Adding tag 'regex' would probably help regex experts actually *see* your question?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the question with proper formatting

Comment: @عمرعيسى What does this data look like? Can you add some example data and the expected outcome to the question?